# Make Access background be invisible when launching it from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, background, hide

I have used this [code for hiding the Access window to show only popup forms](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=74).

This is the Load event of the Access "Display Form"

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Visible = True
    fSetAccessWindow (SW_HIDE)
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

This correctly hides the background when I launch Access directly.

In normal use I want to call Access via an Excel command button (code below). The form loads, but the Access window remains visible when it is launched in this way.

Can anyone see why the behaviour is different?

Thanks

```
Sub Clicked_Edit()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ac As Object
    Dim str As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ac = GetObject(, "Access.Application")
    If ac Is Nothing Then
        Set ac = GetObject("", "Access.Application")
        ac.OpenCurrentDatabase 
       "<MyFilePathToDatabase>"
    End If
    AppActivate "Microsoft Access"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set Application.Visible Property to false `ac.Visible = False`

Comment: I have tried inserting this into the code (in a few places), it has not made any difference.

Comment: please add after this line `AppActivate "Microsoft Access"`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this. It has not made a difference.

Comment: I have a workaround. I created a dummy form that Access opens first. This form closes itself and immediately calls a second form (the real home form), which conducts the hiding procedure. This only worked when carried out in conjunction with the suggestion from @Maddy Nikam